# Duplicate search results in spotlight

Tags: ios9, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I have a requirement where I need to use NSUSerActivity and Corespotlight together. I see duplicate search results in spotlight even after I set relatedUniqueIdentifier
=uniqueidentifer.

Here is the steps I implemented in my project.

1) Create all CSSearchableItems in appdeleagte didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

2) Create NSUSerActivity in specific viewcontroller where relatedUniqueIdentifier = uniqueidentifer(CSSearchableItem)

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after adding requiredUserInfoKeys in NSUSerActivity.