# Duplicated display of NSUserActivity in Spotlight

Tags: corespotlight, nsuseractivity, handoff

I know there are several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134733/usage-of-nsuseractivity-and-corespotlight) on this topic out there but they differed to much from my problem.

I am trying to display my `NSUserActivity` in Spotlight Search. For my `NSUserActivity` I am using three APIs: `.isEligibleForHandoff`, `.isEligibleForSearch` and `.isEligibleForPrediction`.

My problem is that my activity is being displayed twice in the Spotlight Search and that one of the results delivers an empty userInfo and the other one doesn't. However the [Apple Programming Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732192/duplicate-search-results-in-spotlight) suggests:

> Use the following strategies to avoid creating duplicate
>   representations of a single item:
>
> If you’re using both NSUserActivity and Core Spotlight APIs to index
>   an item, use the same value for relatedUniqueIdentifier and
>   uniqueIdentifier to link the representations of the item.

But I don't think this is even my problem since I am not using any Core Spotlight APIs.

Thats my code inside my `UIResponder` class:

```
let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeItem as String)
attributeSet.title = "Place Order Search"
attributeSet.contentDescription = "Get Your Avocado Toast Now"
attributeSet.relatedUniqueIdentifier = ActivityType.placeOrder.rawValue

let avocadoToastDictionary = AvocadoToastManger.dictionary(from: avocadoToastOrder)
let jsonAvocadoToastData = json(from: avocadoToastDictionary)
let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: ActivityType.placeOrder.rawValue)
activity.title = "Place Order"
activity.userInfo = ["PlaceOrder.avocadoToast": jsonAvocadoToastData]
activity.requiredUserInfoKeys = ["PlaceOrder.avocadoToast"]
activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Order an Avocado Toast"
activity.keywords = ["Order", "Avocado Toast"]
activity.isEligibleForHandoff = true
activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
activity.contentAttributeSet = attributeSet

self.userActivity = activity
activity.becomeCurrent()
```

Note: The `updateUserActivityState(activity:)` method is getting called twice in a row.

So how can I void getting multiple search results in the Spotlight Search and make sure the one which has the `userInfo` property set stays.